# Find the value which satisfies these equations

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$C = 0.6Y +50$$

$$I=10$$

We want to find the $Y$ for which $Y=C+I$. This is a question in a chapter about discrete dynamic models, so we have to use an appropriate method.

I tried to rewrite it and ended up with $y = 1\dfrac{2}{3} C - 73 \dfrac{1}{3}$, but that was a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really familiar with DDMs, but algebra says:

$$
\begin{align}
Y &= C + I \\
\implies Y &= 0.6Y + 50 + 10 \\
\implies 0.4 Y &= 60 \\
Y &= \dfrac{60*10}{4} \\
&= 150
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You want $C+I=Y$, so note that $I=10$.

$C+10=Y\implies 0.6Y+50+10=Y\implies 0.6Y+60=Y\implies0.6Y-1Y=-60\implies -0.4Y=-60\implies 0.4Y=60\implies Y=\frac{60}{0.4}=150$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything complicated about this problem.  Just straightforward method.  All you need to do is to perform the substitution for $Y = C + I$.  You should get:

$$Y = C + I$$
$$Y = (0.6Y + 50) + 10$$
$$Y = 0.6Y + (50 + 10)$$
$$Y = 0.6Y + 60$$
$$Y - 0.6Y = 60$$
$$0.4Y = 60$$
$$2Y/5 = 60$$
$$Y = 60 * 5/2$$
$$Y = 150$$